# Can access admin page (now), but not any site pages...yii not found http execption

Tags: error-message, yii, error-templates

Have not accessed my local .test sites in a bit.  I tried today.  I am getting a series of errors.

At first I could not access any page to include the admin page.  I ran Composer update from the command line (within a site's directory) and then updated Craft from the command line (.\ craft update all).  I can now access the admin page and successfully login, but I am still getting errors trying to access the actual site's home page (or any page other than the admin page).

`HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException`
`Template not found: login`

All my templates are located here...(according to Finder)  `/Users/myname/Documents/Websites/mysite/templates/index.twig`

Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming Craft 3 because of composer, but you didn't say.

To start with look in your craft templates folder. I would suggest that you simply don't have the template that Craft is looking for.

If you visit the root of your site this is normally `templates/index.twig` make sure this is present and has no further includes in it (just until you get it working)

Also try looking in `storage/logs/web.log` for errors.

Comment: Yep. Craft 3.  macOS Catalina.  All my templates and my index.twig files are where they were.

Comment: @Hellyar did you run migrations ? Not that I think that would cause those errors. What happens on your index page (site root)? What do the logs say ?

Comment: No, I did not run migrations.  Error on index page is can't find layout

Comment: Twig Template Loading Error – craft\web\twig\TemplateLoaderException

Unable to find the template “_layout” in "index" at line 1.  But it is where it should be